# IOS - SWRevealController - Random swipe issues

Tags: ios, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I have implemented the `SWRevealViewcontroller` (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) - into our `IOS` app and I'm noticing an intermittent swipe issue.

To explain - the basic setup is as follows

[image]

Two left and right swipe screens away from the main screen which is initially a `uitableviewcontroller`.

My issues is that - occasionally if you have swiped up and down the table view - the left and right swipe is ignored it seems there is a conflict between the swipe events used for the `tableviewcontroller` and the `revalview`.

Not sure if anyone else has experienced this or whether its simply a `IOS` bug with multiple swipe events - but if anyone else has experienced a similar issue or has any advice please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this also, most notably when swiping to delete table view rows.

I think that the SWRevealViewController's pan gesture recognizer is basically eating the swipe gestures I'm anticipating seeing when trying to delete a row.

I'm not entirely sure, yet, but I think the solution may be to add this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

to the `SWRevealViewController` Class along with the other `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods.

I'm still doing some testing to see if this really clobbers anything, but I'd love to have other people looking at this fix/solution to see if there are issues to watch out for.

**EDIT**: I also have a [fork](https://github.com/frankfle/SWRevealViewController) of SWRevealViewController in which I've extended the delegate so that you can specify this for yourself.  I've also created a pull request, so we'll see if this fix/enhancement is valued.

Comment: Hi, this enable swipe gesture detection but my swipe gesture will also enable pan gesture as well. Do you have any idea to resolve this?